# Code only reading the first row of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I want to read the 1st column of each row of a CSV file in order to try and find a value. Currently I have this:

```
def checkForCable(idNum):
    with open("test.txt") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[0] == idNum:
                print("matching barcode found")
                return True
            else:
                print("barcode not on file. Adding...")
                return False
```

But this seems to only check the first column of the first row and then stop, rather than checking all of the first columns of the n rows in the CSV file. For instance if row[0] in column 0 is not equal to the number it's searching for, then it won't proceed to check row[0] in column 1 etc. and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the code:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    if row[0] == idNum:
        print("matching barcode found")
        return True
    else:
        print("barcode not on file. Adding...")
        return False
```

This `for` loop does indeed process every row if you let it, but you are *not* letting it because both your true and false parts of the `if` statement return after reading the first row, effectively ignoring all the others.

---

What you probably need is this scheme: if you don't find it in the first row, don't immediately return false - you need to check all the *other* rows and return false only if it's in *none* of them.

In other words, something like this:

```
# Check ALL rows.

for row in csv_reader:
    # If found in THIS row, notify success.

    if row[0] == idNum:
        print("matching barcode found")
        return True

# If found in NO rows, notify failure.

print("barcode not on file. Adding...")
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas. Pandas is very excellent in dealing with csv files.

```
import Pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('csv_file')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)

# Check if Dataframe is empty using empty attribute
if df['Columnname'].empty == True:
    print('Barcode is empty')
else:
    print('Barcode is not empty')
```

Comment: Pandas is very excellent and quick in scripting the codes, it is advisable to use pandas when dealing with CSV :D

Comment: Pandas is a huge dependency; it's overkill if you just want to filter a single csv file.

Comment: If the csv file contains thousands of thousands of rows